# How to create custom skill in azure-search?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

how to integrate the custom skill(Azure function) with azure search, is it mandatory to create the index, indexer and data Source. If it is so, then how to create it.
After going through Microsoft doc i did not get much help. it only create the custom skill for Bing search.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you go through this [Azure Cognitive Search knowledge mining workshop](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-knowledge-mining/tree/master/workshops), modules 0 to 4 (or more if you are interested!). It will show you how all the pieces work together, and walk you through an example where you will create everything including a custom skill (also in an Azure Function) that's integrated with the ingestion flow.

If you're looking for something more specific on how to integrate a custom skill inside a skillset, as part of the enrichment pipeline, [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-custom-skill-interface) should help as well.

Comment: Thanks.. Module 4 help me out